# Basic Algebraic Topology Problem

Tags: algebraic-topology

I've just started learning Algebraic Topology on my own and I came across this problem.

> Let $X \subset R^2$ consist of the union of the 4 lines $x = 0$,
> $x = 1$, $y = 0$ and $y = 1$. Prove that the fundamental group of X is
> isomorphic to the additive group of the integers (Z, +).

I don't know how to approach this and I feel like there's some fact/result that I'm unaware of that's needed here (Other of course than the fact that the fundamental group of $S^1$ is isomorphic to the integers). I would appreciate just being told said result as a hint to get me started.

Comment: First of all, try to show that the boundary of the unit square $[0,1]^2$ is a deformation retract of $X$, and so has the same fundamental group. And the square is homeomorphic to $S^1$.

Comment: Your space is a square with some extra "antennas". Such antennas do not affect the homotopy type (this is basically a reformulation of @Mark 's comment).

Comment: I see. Deformation retract was the notion I was unfamiliar with. Much obliged.